# Executing node script with custom arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I have node.js script, that uses `-b arg1` and `--parameter arg2` arguments. Is there any method do pass them with Grunt task?

I have tried [grunt-execute](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-execute),

```
execute: {
            options: {
                args :['-b test']
            },
            target: {
                src: ['uploader.js']
            }
        },
```

But there was always space before `test`

Answer (score 1):

You can use execSync directly:

```
var cmd = 'node uploader.js -b arg1 --parameter arg2';
var opts = { cwd: process.cwd() };
var result = require('child_process').execSync(cmd, opts).toString().trim();
```

see: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options